# Font inconsistency between question vs. answer links

Tags: bug, status-completed, css, user-interface

I just noticed that, when I look at the hover dialog that shows my recent rep changes, some of the links look different than the others:

[image: Screenshot]

Looking at the source in Firebug reveals why: some of the links (the +2 edits) point to questions and have the class `question-hyperlink`, while the others point to answers and have the class `answer-hyperlink`.  In the site CSS, the former class is styled as:

```css
font-family: "Segoe UI","Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans","DejaVu Sans","Bitstream Vera Sans","Liberation Sans",Verdana,"Verdana Ref",sans serif;
```

whereas the latter inherits the default font family specified for the `body` tag:

```css
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```

IMO, this looks silly and inconsistent.  Shouldn't the answer links be given the same font as the question links, or shouldn't the fonts just be overridden for the profile popup?

Comment: Well spotted Ilmari!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, > rev 2012.5.9.2508.